How do I change the Icon of a JLabel dynamically?
I want to implement an algorithm that simulates data rolling using the Java Swing library and the Apache NetBeans IDE. I've looked at links to similar questions here on the forum but I really either didn't understand the bureaucracy involved in using Images or the examples in the questions were far removed from my problem.
The first code is the code for my program. The second code uses a different logic so that you can test it on your machines without needing access to my images: instead of simulating the roll of the dice by changing the Icon, the code will change the text of the JLabel. Essentially, my problem appears in both cases.
MY OBJECTIVE: I want the JLabel (dice) icon to change between the 6 faces, at 150 ms intervals, for a total of 3 repetitions. After face 6 appears on the 3rd repetition, I want a random face of the dice to be placed on the JLabel, marking the end of the dice roll.
THE PROBLEM: after face 6 appears in the 3rd repetition, face 1 is shown and the dice roll ends.
EDIT: Thank you all very much. I did the debugging suggested by a fellow forum member and discovered that the problem was a logical flaw in the conditional structure of my Timer. Immediately below are the debug code and corrected code.
private void rollDiceDebug(JLabel dice) {
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count == 3) {
                System.out.println("Random face");
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            }
            if (index < faces.size()) {
                System.out.println(count + " : " + index);
                index++;
            } else {
                count++;
                index = 0;
            }
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(150, taskPerformer);
    timer.start();
}


private void rollDice(JLabel dice) {
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count == 19) {
                dice.setIcon(faces.get(random.nextInt(faces.size())));
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            } else if (index < faces.size()) {
                dice.setIcon(faces.get(index));
                index++;
            } else {
                index = 0;
            }
            count++;
        }
        
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(200, taskPerformer);
    timer.start();
}

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private ArrayList<String> dicesPaths = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
    "images/dado1.png", "images/dado2.png", "images/dado3.png", "images/dado4.png",
    "images/dado5.png", "images/dado6.png"));
    private ArrayList<ImageIcon> faces = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Game() {
        initComponents();
        for (String pathDice : dicesPaths) {
           try {
               BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(pathDice));
               ImageIcon face = new ImageIcon(img);
               faces.add(face);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        dice = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        startButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        dice.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\TRABALHOS_POO\\teste\\TesteK\\images\\dado1.png")); // NOI18N
        dice.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0), 2));

        startButton.setText("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                startButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(215, 215, 215)
                .addComponent(dice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 184, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(startButton)
                .addGap(164, 164, 164))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(200, 200, 200)
                        .addComponent(dice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(221, 221, 221)
                        .addComponent(startButton)))
                .addContainerGap(178, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void rollDice(JLabel dice) {
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = 0;
            int count = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (count == 3) {
                    dice.setIcon(faces.get(random.nextInt(faces.size())));
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                }
                if (index < faces.size()) {
                    dice.setIcon(faces.get(index));
                    index++;
                } else {
                    count++;
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
            
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(150, taskPerformer);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        startButton.setVisible(false);
        rollDice(dice);
    }                                           

    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Game().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel dice;
    private javax.swing.JButton startButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private ArrayList<String> dicesPaths = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
    "images/dado1.png", "images/dado2.png", "images/dado3.png", "images/dado4.png",
    "images/dado5.png", "images/dado6.png"));
    private ArrayList<ImageIcon> faces = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Game() {
        initComponents();
        for (String pathDice : dicesPaths) {
           try {
               BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(pathDice));
               ImageIcon face = new ImageIcon(img);
               faces.add(face);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        dice = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        startButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        dice.setText("SASAS");
        dice.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0), 2));

        startButton.setText("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                startButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(215, 215, 215)
                .addComponent(dice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 184, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(startButton)
                .addGap(164, 164, 164))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(200, 200, 200)
                        .addComponent(dice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(221, 221, 221)
                        .addComponent(startButton)))
                .addContainerGap(178, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void rollDice(JLabel dice) {
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = 0;
            int count = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (count == 3) {
                    dice.setText(dicesPaths.get(random.nextInt(dicesPaths.size())));
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                }
                if (index < faces.size()) {
                    dice.setText(dicesPaths.get(index));
                    index++;
                } else {
                    count++;
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
            
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(150, taskPerformer);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        startButton.setVisible(false);
        rollDice(dice);
    }                                           

    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Game().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel dice;
    private javax.swing.JButton startButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}```



The logic is in your code, not in the IDE. The IDE in this case has nothing to do with the problem to solve. You should remove it from the title.

@aled Right. I had already asked a question similar to this on the forum, but one of the answers involved creating a class that inherited JLabel and had its own algorithm for moving the dice. But that example doesn't help me much, because using Netbeans it's difficult to control the inherent code of my JLabel

Could you expand about why Netbeans is making it difficult to solve this? That is useful context to have in the question. Please [edit] the question to add details.

@aled I missed the comment that gave the suggestion I was talking about. But basically, I would need to create a class called 'Dice' that would inherit JLabel. Dice would have its own algorithm to change the icon dynamically using methods that had something to do with 'painting', but the JLabel I create using the Netbeans interface is already a ready-made object, which I can't choose the class it inherits.

As I mentioned in the previous version of this question (which seems to have been deleted for some reason): better to load your files/images as resources:
Netbeans
Eclipse Also, a point of comprehension: there's no such word as "dices" in English. The singular is 'die' and the plural 'dice'

@g00se The use of images is something I really need to research. Thanks for the warning about using the word “dices”

Yes, plus you get the added benefit of the classloader (which is what's used to load resources) caching resources by default

Using a GUI builder forces you to learn the intricacies of the GUI builder, rather than learning Java Swing.
Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.
I modified the rollDice method so you can see the numbers changing.  I slowed down the Swing Timer to 1 second so you can see the change.  I changed the die face 8 times rather than 3 times.
Here's the modified rollDice method.
private void rollDice(JLabel dice) {
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int randomInt = random.nextInt(dicesPaths.size());
            if (count >= 8) {
                dice.setText(Integer.toString(randomInt));
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            } else {
                dice.setText(Integer.toString(randomInt));
                count++;
            }
        }

    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
    timer.start();
}

Edited to add: If you insist on the generated die numbers being unique each time, you have to generate a List of image indexes and shuffle the List.
Here's the modified code.
   private List<Integer> randomizeDie() {
        List<Integer> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int index = 0; index < dicesPaths.size(); index++) {
            valuesList.add(Integer.valueOf(index));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(valuesList);
        
        return valuesList;
    }

    private void rollDice(JLabel dice, List<Integer> valuesList) {
        ActionListener TaskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            int count = 0;
            int index = 0;
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (count >= 8) {
                    dice.setText(Integer.toString(valuesList.get(index)));
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                } else {
                    dice.setText(Integer.toString(valuesList.get(index)));
                    count++;
                }
                index++;
                index %= dicesPaths.size();
            }

        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, TaskPerformer);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        startButton.setVisible(false);
        List<Integer> valuesList = randomizeDie();
        rollDice(dice, valuesList);
    }    

           


Thanks for your comment, but it didn't work very well in my code. 1) the JLabel text doesn't change correctly, there aren't 8 changes, it seems that the change is stuck.
But I'm going to stick with your algorithm, because I understand how it works, all that's left is to solve the issue of the speed of the change and the reason why the “bearing” is stuck. If that's solved, I'll be able to test the change with the setIcon() method.

I'll take a look at the link you sent, but I think my problem is simple to solve. If you or anyone else can check this bearing locking issue, I'd be very grateful

@Vitor Lira: There aren't always going to be 8 die changes because you can get the same random number twice or thrice in a row.  I tested the code before I posted it with your GUI generated code and it works for me.

Oh, that's exactly what it is. Well, then I'll test it with the Icon change. But tell me something: if I wanted to do the dice scrolling without repeating faces, as the original code in my question does, would it be as simple as the code you showed me?

@Vitor Lira: No, it wouldn't.  I'm working on that now.

Okay. Well, I'm going to modify my code as you suggested and continue with the program. If you're still committed to finishing what you're doing, send the code here for me to take a look at. Thank you in advance for your help.

Not an answer but a follow up to my suggestion in your last posting on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78910244/131872 to add debug code.
First as Gilbert suggested you need to slow the Timer down so you can see results easier.
Then you need to actually add debug code. In your second example which is the example we can test without images, in the Timer code I added:
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(count + " : " + index);

From this it is obvious your test code is wrong because your Icon list is empty.
It is solved by simply doing:
//if (index < faces.size()) {
  if (index < dicesPaths.size()) {

Now you can actually test and see some values and analyze your logic to see if it is correct.
Also I changed:
//startButton.setVisible(false);

so I don't have to continually restart the program.

Thank you very much. I debugged it as you suggested and realized that the problem lay in the logical failure of my ifs. It was a very simple problem.
